# replace linebreak with \r\n when sending back to database

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, winforms

Newbie here again.
I have a form in c# that retrieves by calling a Web Service information from a database. One field it gets is just "notes" regarding this client. 
The form i have allows multiple lines in the Notes field, but when i save it (send it via webservice to the database back) it doesn't recognize line breaks. How can i tell it to replace line breaks with the /r/n/ (is that right?) code, so when it retrieves it next time from the database it will know how to display it in the notes field?

This is the code i am using now which doesn't work.

```
     if (MasterRecord.Customer.Notes.Trim().Length < 1)
        {
            string s = "";
            foreach (object o in txtNotes.Text)
            {
                s += o.ToString() + ("\r\n");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Take a gander at [`String.Replace(String,String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)? I like [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) myself, but it's the same-same, really.

Comment: @IzzyG, the reason your code doesn't work is because the Text property of a textbox control doesn't support IEnumerable - the interface necessary for a foreach loop. Can you post the code that you save the data to the database (in the webservice). If you use a parameterised stored proc IMHO you wont have this problem of replacing Carriage Returns/Line Feeds. Also if the Customer.Note has any value ie Length > 0 then it wont go into if statement...

Comment: @JeremyThompson What does a parameterised stored proc have to do with the question?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this - the line breaks should be persisted from your form, through the web service and into the database, and back again.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst I agree you shouldn't have to do this, but I was curious to know the method used to save data, eg if text is inserted into the dB using a adhoc method you have to tweak the sql a bit, eg  apostrophe's require to be delimited with another apostrophe (sproc parameters take care of that) and I was wondering if there was anything funky going on like that with line feeds.

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
var stringToInsert = txtNotes.Text.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are saving multiline text in sql server then replace carriage return with your Custom NewLine specifier for example : %NL%

```
txtNote.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "%NL%");
```

and when you retrieving from database field then follow the reveres approach:

```
MasterRecord.Customer.Notes.Replace("%NL%", Environment.NewLine);
```

if you access this on .net platform then all ok.. i am not confirm about the the another platforms which acess this webserivce..

it works but it is trick to process data through application it saves %NL% in the field value.

Comment: it works! thanks! do you see any reason why in the actual DataBase i don't see the "%NL%" etc? it has it hidden i think, because when i copy the field content it does have line breaks, im just concerned if this wont work on all types of computers running this application, or that this isnt the best way to save line breaks to a database ?

Comment: i do see it in the database, im sorry i was looking in the wrong field oooops
anyhow, anyone know if there is a better way to do it? i know this works, but im always looking to make sure its the best possible way, i know some use /r/n etc ?

Comment: im getting an exception cought if i open the form if its a new user i am entering info for

Comment: it will not cause any error or exception if you are using better code.. i am using this trick in one of my website and working correctly... there may be some other reason of exception..